# TextView is not visible on Android

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I am using three line on center of the screen ; first two line is visible but last line(Textview andhave) is not visible

i have share full xml file please see

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text=" Daily listing "
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/li" />

    </RelativeLayout>

       <TextView
           android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc"
           android:id="@+id/txtprev"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:background="@color/listhead"

           android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/txtprev"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" >

    </ListView>
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/belowtext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:background="@color/listhead"
           android:layout_below="@+id/list"
           android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            />

      <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnprev"
          android:background="@drawable/prev"
          android:layout_width="90dp"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/belowtext"
           android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         />
      <Button
          android:background="@drawable/next"
          android:layout_width="90dp"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:id="@+id/btnnext"
          android:layout_below="@+id/belowtext"
          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         />

      <RelativeLayout 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_below="@+id/btnprev"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:id="@+id/txttxt">

           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arethese"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:text="Are these the property you are looking for? "
           android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            />
           <RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/loginlayout"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/arethese">
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ifnot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:text="If not, "
           android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            />
           <TextView
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ifnot"
            android:id="@+id/txtlogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:text="login "
           android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            />

            <TextView
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtlogin"
            android:id="@+id/orcontinue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:text="or continue your "
           android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            />

             <TextView
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/orcontinue"
            android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:text="search "
           android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            />

           </RelativeLayout>

      </RelativeLayout>

           <TextView
           android:layout_below="@+id/txttxt"
           android:id="@+id/andhave"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:text="@string/andhave"
           android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/login"
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

          android:background="@drawable/greenrounded"
          android:text="Register" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/search"
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

          android:background="@drawable/greenrounded"
          android:text="Search" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Last `Textview` andhave and have is not showing

Please suggest me , what i am doing worng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code : Hope you get Best result. If not get back me :) Before posting the code format the code well. You missed some code lines because of it :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/bottomRelLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/txttxt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnprev"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arethese"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Are these the property you are looking for? " />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/arethese"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ifnot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="If not, " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtlogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ifnot"
            android:text="login " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orcontinue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtlogin"
            android:text="or continue your " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/orcontinue"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="search " />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/andhave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txttxt"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="and Have" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Textview andhave is out of RelativeLayout element

Answer (score 0):

Put the last TextView with ID "andhave" into the RelativeLayout.

(in your code, above the 2nd `</RelativeLayout>` I'd say)

Make sure to keep your views in Layouts.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because your last `Textview` is outside the main layout.
put all your stuff inside

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + B  ----- to build your project if you made a change in you layout XML. (Eclipse)
Then:

Set setContentView(R.layout.you_xml_file);  inside onCreate

Then declare it......

That is